# Fix my mental model for this Exclude reimplementation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I try to implement a custom Exclude utility type, in this [TS challenge](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/questions/43-easy-exclude/README.md) :

I don't really understand a way of using a generic in TS. Can you explain to me this magic?

For context, Exclude utility type makes this :

```
Exclude<"a" | "b" | "c", "a"> => "b" | "c"
```

And the solution of the challenge is :

```
type MyExclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T
```

What I don't understand is that when I declare `MyExclude<"a" | "b" | "c", "a">`, in my comprehension I bound the T generic parameter to this exact type "a" | "b" | "c".

So how in the ternary operator T can possibly be `"b" | "c"` afterwards?

Comment: Read about [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).